# Ansible: Set Tags per Item in a Loop

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to set `tags` per each item in a `with_item` statement?

Assume I have a task:

```
- name: ensure required packages are installed
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - package_1
    - package_2
  sudo: yes
```

When user defines `--tags "second"` in a command line I want only `package_2` to be installed.

Is it possible to do with `tags` expression or any other ways to get desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. The yum module (which I imagine is similar to apt) [states](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html):

> When used with a loop of package names in a playbook, ansible
>   optimizes the call to the yum module. Instead of calling the module
>   with a single package each time through the loop, ansible calls the
>   module once with all of the package names from the loop.

You would need to split the command into two seperate package tasks with tag "second" on the package_2 task.

**EDIT**

See below of an example of iterating a collection with a when condition so it only prints the second item with the correct tag. Hopefully this helps.

```
---
- name: Only run certain items in a list
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
      - name: Echo items based on a tag condition
        shell: echo {{item.cmd}}
        with_items:
           - {cmd: 'package_1', tag: 'first'} 
           - {cmd: 'package_2', tag: 'second'}
        when: item.tag == "second"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that explains only behaviour with `apt` command. But I gave it as an example (probably not very accurate).
Let say there is another command like `command: make {{ item }}` or `debug: msg="{{ item }}"`. So my question was if it is possible to assign different tags to items in loops in general.

Comment: I've amended to cover the general case of a collection with a when condition.

Comment: Seems that proposed solution is the only one at the moment. Unfortunately, it forces user to specify extra argument in command line: `--tags "second" --extra-vars "items_tags=second"`; and use this `items_tags` in the condition.

Comment: I'm not aware of tags being available as variables, so yes you would need two different parameters at  the command line. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/vRlwVcPvV8o mentions this is not available, although this was back in 2013 so may be on the roadmap. Depending on your playbooks it may be best to avoid tags and just use a single variable to run particular tasks, with when: conditions rather than tag:.

Answer (score 6):

I was wondering the same thing 5 years later and I happend to land on this thread. After some experimenting I found the following to work rather successfully without needing to specify extra variables. It'll also work with --skip-tags as well.

Example 1: Using custom tag names:

```
- name: ensure required packages are installed
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=present
  loop:
    - {pkg_name: package_1, tag: first}
    - {pkg_name: package_2, tag: second}
    - {pkg_name: package_3, tag: third}
  sudo: yes
  when:
    - (ansible_run_tags == ['all'] and ansible_skip_tags == []) or (item.tag in ansible_run_tags) or (item.tag not in ansible_skip_tags and (item.tag in ansible_run_tags or ansible_run_tags == ['all']))
  tags:
    - always
```

Tested following scenarios:

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml --tags first
  Installs only the first package.

ansible-playbook test.yaml --skip-tags first
  Installs only the second and third packages.

ansible-playbook test.yaml --skip-tags first --tags third
  Installs only the third package (because 'second' isn't in the tag list.)
```

For the sake of simplification, I may consider using the actual package names as tags. In which case I present...

Example 2: Using package names as tag names:

```
- name: ensure required packages are installed
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=present
  loop:
    - httpd
    - ansible
    - docker
  sudo: yes
  when:
    - (ansible_run_tags == ['all'] and ansible_skip_tags == []) or (item in ansible_run_tags) or (item not in ansible_skip_tags and (item in ansible_run_tags or ansible_run_tags == ['all']))
  tags:
    - always
```

Expected results (not tested):

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml --tags ansible
  Installs only the 'ansible' package

ansible-playbook test.yaml --skip-tags httpd
  Installs only the 'ansible' and 'docker' packages skipping 'httpd'.

ansible-playbook test.yaml --tags mongodb
  Installs nothing since 'mongodb' is not in the list.

ansible-playbook test.yaml
  Installs all packages in the list.
```