# Ansible - Access tags at run time

Tags: jinja2, ansible

How can I access the tags and skip-tags passed via command line to an ansible playbook at run time?

I am trying to achieve a `with_items` loop that can skip or include items based on tag/skip-tag using a `when` clause. [This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648604/ansible-set-tags-per-item-in-a-loop) touches on the same topic but takes a different approach.
I would evaluate the existence of a tag per iteration.

For example:

```
-  name: Build docker images
    docker_image:
        name: "{{item.name}}"
        path: "{{build_folder}}/dockerfiles/{{item.name}}"
        dockerfile: "{{item.name}}.Dockerfile"
        state: build
        tag: "{{private_docker_registry}}/{{item.name}}"
    when: "{{ansible_host_vars['tags'][image1]}}" is defined
    with_items: 
        - image1
        - image2
        - image3
```

Comment: Looks like there is a feature request for [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12003) Doesn't appear to be getting any attention though :/

Answer (score 9):

Since 2.5, ansible added some magic variables to access at runtime. Some of them is `ansible_run_tags`. It seems to be what you needed.

Ref: [Ansible 2.5 change logs](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.5/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.5.rst#minor-changes-4)

Answer (score 2):

Tags are not available at runtime. Tags define what tasks will be executed. You can use this to translate tags to facts:

```
- set_fact:
    image1: True
  tags: image1

- set_fact:
    image2: True
  tags: image2

- set_fact:
    image3: True
  tags: image3
```

Now you have facts corresponding to your tags and can use them in your condition:

```
...
when: hostvars[inventory_hostname][item] == True
with_items:
  - image1
  - image2
  - image3
```

But for me this feels wrong. This is not the purpose of tags. Tags should not define what software is installed on a host. This should be defined in your group/host vars. Tags then should simply limit the play to a subset of tasks, for example to update packages, to restart services, etc.

Beside tags you could archive the same with extra-vars. This also gives you more control. If you call your playbook without any tags provided, all tasks will be executed.